# Local admin user created via GPO has no adequate permission

Tags: group-policy

I have created a Local Admin user for my IT support team via group policy (Win2012R2), now the they can use this user for logging into computers but it seems that they do not have privilege to change network setting on the computers.

Comment: Do you create local user or add domain user to local admin group wia GPP?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious answers are that the user accounts are not being successfully created as local administrators, or the particular settings are controlled by GPO (which local admins can't override in a domain).

Are the user acounts actually showing up as members of the local administrators group on the systems in question? If so then they *are* local admins, so you should then check that the settings people are trying to change are not being centrally managed.